# Symbol not found, but library is imported

Tags: netbeans, base64, java

I am using Netbeans and I am trying to use the base64 library, but it gives me "cannot find symbol"

```
OutputStream b64 = new Base64.OutputStream(os);
```

First I tried adding it like this

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Which gives me a package does not exist, so I went to this website and downloaded the jar file. I downloaded for more than one website, but last one was http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscodecjar.htm

I added the library by right click on libraries, add Jar/Folder and selecting the .jar file that was downloaded. This gives me a package does not exist.

Can someone explain to me why this happens.

Note: My goal is to use java robot to copy a part of the screen and send it as a post request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the jar from Apache: http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi

The desired package and class is available in the jar i.e. `commons-codec-1.7.jar`

```
    org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

Add the above Jar from this distribution and let me know, if you still get the issue.

Though I think, to get the output stream, you would want to use [**org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64OutputStream**](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64OutputStream`:

```
OutputStream b64 = new Base64OutputStream(os);
```

This will require Apache's [commons-codec.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.7/commons-codec-1.7.jar) on your classpath.

Comment: Still doesnt work
Base64OutputStream underlined
unused import
cannot find symbol

Comment: Download the jar above & make sure you import the `Base64OutputStream` class. :)